# Why does adding ":remote => true" cause my file download not to launch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, ruby-on-rails-5, link-to, link-to-remote

I’m using Rails 5.  I have set up this link for downloading a file

```
<%= link_to image_tag("cc_icon.png"), scenario_download_cc_path(subscription.scenario), :remote => true %>
```

which links to this controller method

```
def download_cc
  scenario = Scenario.find(params[:scenario_id])
  send_data scenario.cc_data, filename: "#{scenario.title}.imscc", type: 'application/zip', :disposition => 'attachment'
end
```

But when I click on the link above, even though I see a remote call being made, no file download appears in my browser (I’ve tried this on both Chrome and Firefox).  How do I make this work?  Note, removing “remote => true” is not an option because then the URL in my address bar changes, which I don’t want.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen the remote option used with file downloads. It's mostly designed for AJAX form posting and URL hits like deleting a record or action calls that make sense to do over AJAX.

If you want the link to force a "Save As..." dialog, use the `download` attribute in the link. A 'bare' download attribute will force the "Save As..." dialog. Its value will be the download filename. So `<a href="/my/download/action" download="file_100.zip">` opens a dialog prompting you to save `file_100.zip`.

Comment: How would I write this in Rails (form of "link_to")?  The file "file_100.zip" doesn't exist -- as you can see from my controller code, it is served as binary data from a database.

Comment: @Natalia <%= link_to image_tag("cc_icon.png"), scenario_download_cc_path(subscription.scenario), download: "#{subscription.scenario.title}.imscc" %>

Comment: Thanks but when doing that the URL in the address bar changes, which I don't want.  I thought adding "remote => true" would prevent such a change but I guess I was wrong about that.